# How to show alert Dialog when home button is pressed ?(ICS)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-homebutton

I want to show alert when user presses home button on device(do you want to exit the app ?)
How to do it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't handle Home button click, because of Android policy ([Home button click event handling android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893585/home-button-click-event-handling-android)). Of course, you can use onPause()/onStop() method of your current Activity, but your application will be moved to background too quick and user will not see your dialog, I think.

Also, note that Home not closes the app - just moves to background. User usually close app by pressing Back on main activity, try to handle it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your dialog here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is not possible for Android apps to override the functionality of the home button. The best you can do is show the dialog when the user presses back in your topmost `Activity`.

You can find more information at the following SO answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7240268/3214339

[Android Overriding home key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039500/android-overriding-home-key)

Answer (score -2):

Write the show alert dialog code in onPause() it will work perfectly.

Comment: It will not work - application will move to background anyway and too quick