# Handling Home press button event when application not open

Tags: android, android-homebutton

i am developing security app on android platform.
now my requirement is to handle **home button** press event when application not open or
not in foreground screen.

is there any way to handle home button event out of application??

Comment: is that mean when you press the button you need to have it run the application ,Is It ?

Comment: @VenushkaT yes some code of my application should run, i need to send notification from my application. when three time home button press continuously when app closed or not in currently on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling detection of pressing home button is no longer supported:

[Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android)

[Home button click event handling android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893585/home-button-click-event-handling-android)

Comment: oh thats a issue , can we detect back key press when application not open ??